# Congratz Kilisi on clipping 200k rep!

Tags: discussion

Congratulations on reaching 200k!

[image: Kilisi]

Besides your answers and posts, it's also been great to have your support as a Mod. As usual, your zen-like style keeps your contributions useful, direct, and on point.

Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Thanks. It's been quite a journey for me here at The Workplace. I've learnt a lot over the years, and I'm proud to be part of such a community.

There's a lot of insightful and intelligent people here, more than once I've had to take a step back and re-evaluate my ideas on how things work, which is great. I'm not used to it in normal working life, so it's healthy and useful exercise.

Comment: Bravo! Tons of great answers!

Comment: Unlikely!! This is one of the longest answers I've seen in a while from K!